# axios in React with API throw "network error" exception

Tags: json, api, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I developed an API using C# (visual studio) and when i send request to get the data using browser or Postman it's return data successfully,
in another hand i developed a react application that do CRUD processes by send the requests to my local API service,
(the visual studio and visual studio code in debug mode) 
When i send request using my react(axios) application the api service get the request but the axios in Get function throw a network error exception,

I tried a lot of solutions exist in google but no result.

When i use another API like (http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/) it's work
but when i use local api (my api) throw a network error

My react code:

```
 import axios from 'axios';
class Faq extends Component {
componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('http://localhost:53419/api/faqs')
            .then(
            response => {
                const faqs = response.data;
                this.setState(this.state.faqs = { faqs });
            }
            )
        .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

My API Service (Controller) code:

```
    public class FAQsController : ApiController
    {
[ResponseType(typeof(FAQs))]
        public List<FAQs> GetFAQs()
        {
            return db.FAQs.ToList();
        }
}
```

My WebAPIConfig.cs file to convert the data to JSON is:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        ((DefaultContractResolver)config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

React package.json configurations:

```
{
  "name": "compare-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bulma": "^0.5.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: are you runing them on different ports (cors)? what error do you get?

Comment: @Sag1v 
API: http://localhost:53419/api/faqs
React: http://localhost:3000/
Same PC